# javascript parsing the date time as specified timezone

Tags: javascript

I am working in boomi middle ware so can't use any libraries like moment js which has the solution that i can use like following:

```
function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}
```

I will be receiving

- the date in the middleware as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
- the date is not UTC. Depending upon the originating request, i know the time zone of this date which could be America/New_York (EST) or  America/Los_Angeles (PST) etc

How can i convert this datetime to UTC?

Here is what i am trying to do

```
var myDate = new Date("2020-02-27 11:19:00").toDateString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"});
document.write(myDate + '<br>'); //.toDateString() toLocaleString
myDate = new Date(myDate);
document.write(myDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + myDate.getDate() + 
                    " " + myDate.getHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + ":" + myDate.getSeconds());
```

and this is resulting in following. I have lost my time.

```
Thu Feb 27 2020
2020-2-27 0:0:0
```

Comment: where do you get the timezone on the request? where is that set?

Comment: i'd really try to get something like moment in since this is not easy to do by yourself

Comment: Depending upon the site, we know the timezone of it. I can't use moment.js etc on BOOMI.

Comment: After spending some time, I am going with a different solution, I am now handling the dates in the C# MicroServices where getting the offset is much simpler and straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you lost your time. That's because you told it to go away!

```
> (new Date()).toDateString()
'Wed Mar 04 2020'
```

You can use

```
> (new Date()).toLocaleString()
'3/4/2020, 10:19:06 AM'
```

However, as you noted in the comments, you also need to invert the offset.

I believe this works:

```
const toUTC = (dateString, timezoneName) => {
  offset = new Date((new Date(0)).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: timezoneName})); // from local time to time-zone time
  return new Date((new Date(dateString)).getTime() - offset.getTime())
}
```

e.g.:

```
> toUTC('2020-02-27 11:19:00', 'America/Chicago')
2020-02-27T17:19:00.000Z
> toUTC('2020-02-27 11:19:00', 'America/New_York')
2020-02-27T16:19:00.000Z
> toUTC('2020-02-27 11:19:00', 'Europe/Berlin')
2020-02-27T10:19:00.000Z
> toUTC('2020-02-27 11:19:00', 'GMT')
2020-02-27T11:19:00.000Z
```

Comment: Wouldn't toLocaleString change the zone to machines zone on which the script is running

Comment: `var myDate = new Date("2020-02-27 11:19:00").toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"});` is resulting in `2/27/2020, 8:19:00 AM
2020-2-27 8:19:0`. It is getting converting to `8:19AM`.

Comment: I am going with a different solution, I am now handling the dates in the C# MicroServices where getting the offset is much simpler and straightforward.

Comment: you are right; it's a good question though. It must be possible by calculating the offsets first. Still working on it.

Comment: Problem is that you can't use constants for the offset. These need to accommodate day light savings. I already have a solution using groovy script in BOOMI but the issue is that i have to change the cross reference table offset minutes twice a year. I wanted to see if javascript can help me work with time zone ids, the way C# lets us do. Unfortunately, i can't use javascript and groovy script implementation has a drawback.

Comment: I just updated my solution. And I don't think it requires you to update any tables on a regular basis. The offset is computed by JS on the fly.

Comment: This comment `// from local time to time-zone time`, basically the time i am receiving is not local. It is for the time zone like America/New_York. I'll test your solution.

Comment: Tested the solution with `var myDate = toUTC('2020-02-27 11:19:00', 'America/Los_Angeles')
document.write(myDate);`. The output is `Thu Feb 27 2020 14:19:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`. now 11:19 am is 7:19 pm UTC.

Comment: that's because your `document.write(myDate)` is "naive", it doesn't know that you want a UTC time. The date object itself stores the timezone, so once you have a correct date, you can print it for whichever time zone you'd like. In your case I think you want `document.write(myDate.toUTCString())`.

Comment: ps: by "naive" I mean the `myDate` date object is naively converted to string (by the famous JS implied type conversion). And that's not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got pulled into another integration issue so couldn't put more effort into this one, plus I implemented a solution utilizing the microservice i have.

Comment: Bug: This method wouldn't differentiate between standard time and daylight time.
[example: `(new Date("2022-07-23T20:54:56.246Z")).toLocaleString("iso",{timeZone:"Asia/Jerusalem"})` is 23:54 (GMT+3), but the same time few months earlier `2022-01-23T20:54:56.246Z` become  22:54 (GMT+2)]

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answer:

```
  const getOffset = (time, timeZone) => (new Date((new Date(time)).toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: timeZone
  })).getTime() - time);

  const toUTCPlus = (dateString, timezoneName) => {
    const epoc = (new Date(dateString)).getTime();
    let offset = getOffset(0, timezoneName);
    offset = getOffset(epoc - offset, timezoneName);
    return new Date(epoc - offset);
  }
```

This "plus" version adjust the offset with daylight saving

Answer (score -1):

> I will be receiving
>
> ```
> the date in the middleware as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
> the date is not UTC. Depending upon the originating request, i know the time zone of this date which could be America/New_York (EST)
> ```
>
> or America/Los_Angeles (PST) etc

```
let datetime = new Date("2020-02-27 11:19:00").toISOString().split('-').join('/')
```

example in my console:

```
new Date("2020-02-27 11:19:00").toISOString().split('-').join('/')
"2020/02/27T10:19:00.000Z"
```

Comment: This is not correct. My datetime belongs to the site which is in a specific timezone.

Comment: In my case the datetime could belong to eastern, pacific, mountain. It could be any of these time zones.